# Query on connect()

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, test

Suppose i deployed a contract like this:`const test = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test"); await test.deployed(); const [ signer, acc1, acc2 ] = await ethers.provider.listAccounts()`

So, we know `signer` is connected by default while any function calling from that contract. What if I want to connect `acc1` means i want the function will be called by `acc1`, will i have to do like this - `await test.connect(acc1). function_from_test()`????
If no then how?
And help me to know usage of `connect()`, how to use it?????

Answer (score 0):

In hardhat, to impersonate different signers, you have to do one of the two specified ways:

- Use the `connect()` function on the deployed contract like this [link](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts#using-a-different-account).
- Use the `impersonateAccount` function, to be able to send transactions from an address, like this [link](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks#impersonating-accounts).

The problem with your example is, that you are running the `connect(acc1)` on a factory instance. The correct way would be to deploy the contract first and connect the deployed instance to `acc1`. Would be something like the code below:

```
const TestFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("Test");
const testInstance = await TestFactory.deploy(); 
const [ signer, acc1, acc2 ] = await ethers.getSigners();

await testInstance.connect(acc1).function_from_test();
```

Comment: we can't use acc1.address while using connect(), right?

Comment: I don't think so, connect() expects a singer object as an input. acc1.address passes in the string of a signer's address.